# Jaxb Element Annotation

Tags: java, jaxb, jaxb2

How do i annotate my class to archive this xml structure:

```
<elementTag attribute="false">Testvalue</elementTag>
```

I tried to put elementTag into a seperate class, but then "Testvalue" is not inline as it is in my example.

Thanks and best regards,
m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@XmlValue` annotation.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="elementTag")
public class Root {

     @XmlAttribute
     public String getAttribute {
         return attribute;
     }

     @XmlValue
     public String getValue() {
         return value;
     }

}
```